# linux/solaris expand path c++

Tags: c++, linux, filepath

I'd like to have a function that expands all environment variables passed to it. Something that, when called transforms (assume $HOME=MyHome) "$HOME/foo $HOME/bar ~myname" to "/MyHome/foo /MyHome/bar /usr/xyz/myname" I've found all sorts of things that expand relative paths to absolute paths, but I haven't found anything that does exactly what I want. I expect that this has been done before, but I can't find it.

Comment: [man wordexp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp)

Comment: Doesn't exist on my solaris machines.

Comment: Can't you use [getenv](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) for this?

Comment: @juanchopanza I can use getenv for each instance but it requires me finding all instances of a variable in a string and replacing it myself -- this feels like a common enough problem that someone should have written something that works.

Comment: @juanchopanza He would have to manually do the parsing for that (though really, the parsing should be pretty simple if it's just replacing $var and ~). At dale: Are you sure Solaris doesn't have wordexp? I'm not very familiar with Solaris, but it tends to stick pretty closely to POSIX, right?

Comment: @Corbin I thought it should be on Solaris as well, but when I looked for it I couldn't find it.

Comment: Since Solaris is POSIX compliant you can get a list of all environment variables from `extern char ** environ;` defined in `#include <posix/environ.c>` ... Is it possible for you to use C++11's inbuilt regex or another regular expression library?

Comment: I can't use any C++11 features, but I could write my own, I was just hoping that someone else had one already complete. I don't want to write something that has a subtle bug when I expect someone else has already written something that works nicely. (I'm trying to replace a poorly written function that returns a pointer to a static memory. This code is used in hundreds of places and my change will be hard to test fully.)

Comment: Hmmmm, can you search all of your include folders for `wordexp.h`? Maybe it's just not where you expect. It could be in `posix/wordexp.h` actually instead of just `wordexp.h`. I was actually going to suggest that you just borrow the code from glibc, but after just finding it, that seems like a bad route. The wordexp code in glibc is 53KB (though as far as glibc goes, it's actually not that cryptic).

Comment: @Corbin Weird, I swear I looked, you are correct. It exists, I'll use that.

Comment: @vonbrand it won't let me accept it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in the comments from Corbin:
"""
Hmmmm, can you search all of your include folders for wordexp.h? Maybe it's just not where you expect. It could be in posix/wordexp.h actually instead of just wordexp.h. I was actually going to suggest that you just borrow the code from glibc, but after just finding it, that seems like a bad route. The wordexp code in glibc is 53KB (though as far as glibc goes, it's actually not that cryptic). 
"""

Comment: You need to have the `SUNWhea` package on Solaris for the headers, that function (POSIX.2001) is part of Solaris libc for more than a decade. Rather than rifle through glibc (and give yourself nightmares) you could also lift the code and headers from Gnulib: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/